# Swift iOS: How can I get player's name in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uialertview

I have built a game using SpriteKit and I have it fully functional except for getting the user to input their name to store with their high scores.  I'm using NSUserDefaults to store the scores as an array of their top 5 scores.  I'd like to store their name as well because eventually I plan to move the storage to a server instead of NSUserDefaults to allow for players to compete for high scores.

My thought was to present a UIAlertController when the game first runs on the device, to grab their name via a text input field, then store it in NSUserDefaults.  But no matter where I put the code for UIAlertController (GameScene.swift, GameViewController.swift, and even AppDelegate.swift) it doesn't pop up.

The code I'm using for the alert is:

```
    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Enter Name", message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    ac.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler(nil)

    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { [unowned self, ac] _ in
        let playerName = ac.textFields![0]

        })

    ac.presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This is the UPDATED CODE based on comments below, including the entire viewDidLoad function:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Enter Name", message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    ac.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler(nil)

    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { [unowned self, ac] _ in
        let playerName = ac.textFields![0]

        })

    self.presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)

    if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = false
        skView.showsNodeCount = false

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
        currentGame = scene
        scene.viewController = self
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presenting a view controller won't generally work inside of `viewDidLoad`since it is called after the view is loaded into memory, but before it is presented on the screen (see the view controller lifecycle [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW3)). You can set things up there (like your scenes) but any animations or interactive elements must be done later.

A safer place to put this would be in `viewDidAppear` (along with some logic to make sure it doesn't get repeatedly presented) or in response to a tap on a button.

Also, you have to call `presentViewController` from a view controller that is already on the screen for it to be shown. So, if you have this code somewhere in your `GameViewController`, you could change

```
ac.presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

to

```
self.presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: When I change it to self, it no longer crashes the app, but it doesn't display the alert viewcontroller, and it gives me this error: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7a3efc00> on <Bomb_Drop.GameViewController: 0x79669e70> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: That error message suggests that the GameViewController isn't showing on the screen when you call `presentViewController`. Where in your `GameViewController` class is this code getting called from?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've tried it before and after the scene is created.  I'll post the code in another comment since it won't let me post it here.

Comment: I updated the code in my original question. Thanks again!

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm! Thanks so much for the quick responses!

Answer (score 1):

```
//1. Create the alert controller.            
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Some Title", message: "Enter a text", preferredStyle: .Alert)

//2. Add the text field. You can configure it however you need.
alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ (textField) -> Void in
    textField.text = "Some default text."
})

//3. Grab the value from the text field, and print it when the user clicks OK. 
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
    let textField = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField
    println("Text field: \(textField.text)")
}))

// 4. Present the alert.
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

is that's what you except?
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks like that's basically the code I have, except the "self" part of self.presentViewController.  I tried changing that part though and it still doesn't work.  It looks like it's trying to work, the screen flashes after loading the game scene, but then goes right back to the game scene.